# Sitemap URL redirecting to another

Tags: indexing, sitemap

My new site home is on URL https://fr.mysite.com

I have a sitemap URL based on the same domain: https://fr.mysite.com/sitemap.xml

When this sitemap URL is browsed, the sitemap content (list of sub "sitemap" directives) is displayed through another URL: https://api.mysite.com/sitemap_fr.xml
And all URLs inside this content have URLs based on the initial base URL: https://fr.mysite.com/

So to sum up: https://fr.mysite.com/sitemap.xml redirects to https://api.mysite.com/sitemap_fr.xml to deliver the sitemap content.

This was done by developers for technical reasons but it was not a functional request.

**So my questions are:**

Is it a problem to have this redirection — I mean, in terms of indexing by Google?

Could it prevent Google to index correctly my content for which all URLs have this https://fr.mysite.com/  base URL?

My old website (replaced by this new one) is already well indexed by Google and I would not want to lose my ranking because of this redirection.

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: You would need sitemap to be on the same domain. e.g https://fr.mysite.com/sitemap.xml. There is a lot going on when migrating a site when you want to preserve everything to do with SEO. Which is not what https://stackoverflow.com is for. Have a look at @JohnConde comment.